# What is the most efficient way to index in SQL Server on three nchar columns in this case?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, database-performance

**Abstract:**
I'm creating a new table in SQL Server 2012 as part of a business system design. The table has 3 columns (among others) with type of `nvarchar` of various sizes, my web app needs to query those 3 columns using a single string search term. This table could contain records no more than 100K.

I'd like to index these columns in SQL Server 2012 in a way so that it would be most efficient to get the results.

**I'd like to emphasize that the questions that I'm about to ask pertains to my particular case rather than generic SQL index questions. Though the answers to them might be applied to generic questions as well.**

**Context**

- SQL Server 2012
- Windows Server 2008

Table column definitions:

- ItemNumber :: nvarchar(10)
- Manufacturer :: nvarchar(20)
- Description :: nvarchar(40)

Possible record count: up to 100K

**Use Case:**

An end user (one of 1000 or so) will pass a single string to search these three columns and the query needs to return all rows where any of these 3 columns contains the value of the string that's being searched (case insensitive).

**The Questions:**

1. What is the best way in to create index(s) so that the query would return the data in a most efficient manner (fast while minimizing SQL Server resource usage)?
2. Create index for each column?
3. Create one index with all 3 columns included?
4. Enable full text search on the index(s)?
5. What method would exploit the full potential of what SQL Server 2012 could offer?

Comment: I would ***NOT*** recommend using `char(n)` or `nchar(n)` for anything longer than 5 or maybe max. 10 characters. Do **not** use `nchar(20)` or even worse - `nchar(40)` - this is a **massive** waste of space and you'll never get decent performance with such a design. For anything over 10 characters, I would ***always*** recommend using `varchar/nvarchar(x)` instead of the fixed-length versions .....

Comment: Last comment: if you say *where any of the three columns **contains** the search text*, then you either need to use full-text search, or then you're looking at doing `... ItemNumber LIKE '%searchterm%'` matches will automatically makes sure **no indexes** will ever be used --> your performance will be abysmal....

Comment: @marc_s thanks for all the helpful comments!  I've updated the data type in my posting.  I want the focus of this post to be about efficient indexing in this scenario.

Comment: As I mentioned: if you want to search three columns for *containing a search expression*, then you're best bet is full-text searching. If you search using `... WHERE ItemNumber LIKE '%....%'` - you're making **sure** no indexes will ever be able to be used and your performance will be horrible - no matter what kind of indexes you have

Answer (score 0):

As @marc_s already suggested, Full-text search is the only efficient option.